# laravel error 150 foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, laravel

I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `monkeybussiness`.`#sql-db0_17` (errno: 150 "Foreign key co   nstraint
>   is incorrectly formed")

while the columns are identical as far as I know. Why is this happening?

Events migrations file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEventsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('afspraak_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('titel');
            $table->integer('persoon_id');
            $table->foreign('persoon_id')->references('persoon_id')->on('personen');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('events');
    }
}
```

Personen migrations file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Personen extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('personen', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('persoon_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('voornaam');
            $table->string('achternaam');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I tried `->unsigned()` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I know you said you tried it, but just to reiterate, `$table->integer('persoon_id');` does need to be unsigned.

Comment: I editted my answer to that but still same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Events table was created first. I had to change the date of the filename so that it would be after the `persoon` table. After that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have copied pasted without editing your migration files. Your `personen` migrations has all the same data as 'events'. If that's the case in  your application, then surely the foreign key cannot work because the table does not exist.

If it just an error of copy, make sure you put the correct table name here

```
 $table->foreign('persoon_id')->references('persoon_id')->on('personen');
 //table name should be 'personens' ?
```

Can you try to alias it?

```
$table->foreign('persoon_id', 'fk_persoon_id')->references('persoon_id')->on('personen')
->onDelete('no action')
->onUpdate('no action');
```

Comment: I'm sorry I pasted the same code there accidently.. I corrected it that was my mistake on the question. But the problem is still the same.

Comment: Still same thing: `General error: 1005 Can't create table `monkeybussiness`.`#sql-db0_1b` (errno: 150 "Foreign key co
  nstraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `events` add constraint `fk_persoon_id` foreign key (`persoon_id
  `) references `personen` (`persoon_id`) on delete no action on update no action)`

Comment: But why is it trying to create a table monkeybussiness? That's the name of the database not the table. The tables are `personen` and `events`

Comment: Maybe the error comes from other migrations. Do a project search of `monkeybussiness`

Comment: It's the only laravel project I have on this pc

Comment: Yes, search throughout that project. Do  a string search.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean but these 2 are the only migrations in the project I deleted the default ones and I created these through console with php artisan make